# Uncertainty on using a plural or not in "on your home and work computer"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have a simple question. I am editing a text which says:

> Sign in... *on your home and work computer*, your phone...

My confusion relates to the italicised. The writer is referring to more than one kind of computer, home and work. It should say "on your home and work computers," right?

Saying "on your home and work computer," to me, suggests it is the same computer.

Or, to avoid this issue, should I re-write it to say: "on your home and your work computer."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is not wrong technically, but from the context you can tell what the author intended. The author is not incorrect either; that's one of the beauties of English! The phrase is technically ambiguous, but a particular interpretation is, in the author's opinion, overwhelmingly more likely. In your own writing you're welcome to spell it out less ambiguously, and your suggested change is fine.